# Parsing out string values in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby string car_1_ford  I want the out put to be

car
1
ford

what is the best way in ruby to parse this string?

Comment: Do you want `'car 1 ford'` or `['car', '1', 'ford']` as your result?

Answer (score 6):

```
string = "car_1_ford"

string.gsub!("_", " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to break that string into 3 pieces, then use this code

```
s = 'car_1_ford'
s.split('_')
```

(oh, there's ^ an emoticon :-) )

Result will be this

```
['car', '1', 'ford']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll ever need some more advanced patterns you can use regular expressions.

Here you have [Documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm).

Example:

```
irb(main):012:0> "a_b----c==d".gsub!(/[-_=]+/, ' ')
=> "a b c d"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"car_1_ford".tr('_', ' ') #=> "car 1 ford"
```

If you only substitute a character for another character then the #tr method is nice, and it alows for multiple changes in one go:

```
"car_1_ford#model T".tr('_#', ' :') #=> "car 1 ford:model T"
```